# Netbeans 8.2 No reconoce libreria

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu

Descargue el plugin Java EE Base para Netbeans 8.2, pero cuando intento crear un proyecto Web Aplication, me pide la librería "javaee-endorsed-api-7.0" La descargué y la agregue al Netbeans,pero nada, incluso la agregué directamente desde el proyecto Web pero aún así no reconoce la libreria, muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira si [las respuestas aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47520464/5587982) te sirven para resolver este problema. Ten en cuenta si estás o no usando Maven. Si es así, creo que bastaría con agregar correctamente la dependencia, si no, habrá que descargar el jar correcto y agregarlo al classpath.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió.